# Login Issue, When connected to Proxy

Tags: security, owasp

I wanna do security testing using Owasp Zap tool, I connected chrome browser & Zap tool with Proxy Server. When I tried to Login into my application, I got log in error. I'm able to load the URL still not able to log in. Kindly provide me a suggestion on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need to supply a lot more information than that - it could be any number of problems.

To start with, what is the error reported?

Comment: Issue Resolved! The port number I used in Zap tool was used by another tool, The traffic was cleared when I tried with different port number. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, and glad its now working for you :)